# FirebaseCore 3.4.7 Module inside Google Drive pod corrupts workspace

Tags: google-drive-api

I called today `pod update` and only FirebaseCore was updated from version 3.4.6 to 3.4.7. After that I am getting following error, no matter how many times I clean all the workspace, checkout again, etc. each time I get this new version I end up with the following errors while compiling:

```
duplicate symbol _GSDK_NSClassFromString in:
    .../Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
    ...Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_getClass in:
    ...Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
    ...Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_getProtocol in:
    ...Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
    ...Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_lookUpClass in:
    ...Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
    ..Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Restarting Xcode clears the corruption and allows me to access the workspace. However I still have the duplicate symbol build errors.

Answer (score 12):

Solved removing *-all_load* from *Other Linker Flags* under *Build Settings*

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. I encountered similar errors after installing both Firebase SDK and GoogleMap SDK on my project. After removing -all_load from Other Linker Flags, link error went away.

Comment: Could you please mention what's the "Other Linker Flags" list contains? I'm facing the same issue, I removed *-all_load*, but I got new errors.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question trying to integrate AdMob in a Kivy app for iOS.  Removing *-all_load*  from *Other Linker Flags* , as suggested by David, does allow app to compile without errors, but app will subsequently crash when Kivy instantiates your app.

The solution for my case was to use *-force_load* *path_to_archive* for each archive library in kivy-ios/dist/lib/

Hopefully this saves someone else a bit of searching!